# Does the Oracle have any physical hardware in real world?

Tags: the-matrix

I watched *The Matrix* trilogy and *The Animatrix (2003)*. I heard there is more to it but I never read a single line.

It seems "The Architect" has psychical hardware in real world which in the third movie makes the deal with Neo (spiky baby face machine), but we never see "The Oracle" except in the Matrix.

Does Oracle have a physical form in the real world?

Comment: The Deus ex Machina **isn't the Architect**, at least as far we know; http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Deus_Ex_Machina

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as can be told, **none** of the (program) characters that we meet in the world of the Matrix (The Oracle, The Architect, The Agents, Seraph, The Keymaker, The Merovingian and his henchmen) have a hardware component, with the possible exception of Rama Kandra who's a

> power plant systems manager for recycling operations.

The giant floating head (made up of lots of slaved flying units) seen at the end of The Matrix Revolutions is the [Deus Ex Machina](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Deus_Ex_Machina), a sort of interactive system allowing visitors to the Machine City to interact directly with the Machine Mainframe. This God-head doesn't seem to be under [the direct control of the Architect](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/who-is-the-highest-authority-of-the-machine-world-in-the-matrixverse?rq=1), any more than it controls the other programs we see.

Comment: To clarify, you're saying that none of those programs have *dedicated* hardware?  (I remember reading that the original premise was that the programs all run on the computational power of human brains, and that's why humanity was enslaved, but it was my understanding that this never became canon.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston - As far as can be told, none of the programs in the Matrix have dedicated hardware. They all exist within the Matrix itself.

Comment: And as far as we know, the Matrix itself runs on more-or-less conventional computers?  (I'm not disagreeing with you, I just wondered if I'd overlooked something.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston - We don't really see/know where the construct of The Matrix is running. Presumably inside those big towers.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - There's mention in the non-canon Matrix story "[Goliath](http://web.archive.org/web/20040616032506/http://whatisthematrix.warnerbros.com/rl_cmp/rl_neil_g.html)" that the machines are using the humans for processing power, but that's the sole reference as far as I'm aware

Comment: "_As far as can be told, **none** of the (program) characters that we meet in the world of the Matrix[, including] Seraph[,] have a hardware component_" - so, what's your take on this question? [Why is Seraph gold?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/95787/85712) The accepted answer there seems to claim that the gold code is enough to confirm that Seraph must have hardware. I'm not sure I agree with that myself, though... I'm more of a mind with DavidS's comment on that question...

Comment: @NathanS - I see nothing in that answer that *confirms* that he's gold because he's hardware-based. It's just speculation

Comment: Yeah, that's my point; I suppose it's just that I'm seeing two conflicting statements by two users who have a history of producing solid answers to Matrix questions (yours saying he's software, Null's saying he's hardware), but with no way of knowing which is right... Actually, maybe I'm better off asking a new question about that, rather than basically just poking at you in a comment to some other question... Sorry about that.

Comment: @NathanS - As far as I'm aware there's zero canon confirmation of either statement.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I fear may be true. Well, if I can figure out how to write a question that doesn't just sound like a duplicate of "Why is Seraph gold?" then I might post it in case anyone else has a way to try to shed some light on the matter...