# Does the Matrix have hardware?

Tags: the-matrix

The Matrix is a computer simulation. Most computers have hardware or at least a physical base in the real world. Does the Matrix have any physical/hardware components?

Comment: All computers have hardware. If you have a "virtual" computer, then it will simply be an instance running on one (or several) machines or servers. The Matrix is no different.

Comment: @Moo - The Matrix Comics story *Goliath* suggests that the humans are also being used as processing power for the Matrix.

Comment: Take a look at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12244/did-the-machines-use-humans-brains-as-cpus and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150553/are-there-signs-that-the-matrix-holds-any-technological-resemblance-to-out-of-un

Comment: @Moo but everyone knows the energy battery story doesn't make sense certainly in the real world.  Whereas the linked humans being a very powerful Supercomputer does make sense.  Regardless the fact that users can call in on hardware means there has to be physical wires somewhere- Regardless of whether the cpu is biological or technological.

Comment: I refuse to get into another pointless discussion with Valorum.

Comment: @Moo - I always enjoy our little pointless discussions

Comment: Basically a dupe of [Does the Oracle have any physical hardware in real world?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150202/does-the-oracle-have-any-physical-hardware-in-real-world?rq=1)

Comment: Jumping in just to be annoying, good luck tagging the right user :p

Comment: @Möoz - I see what you did there.