# How come The Architect can make a strong promise like setting people free

Tags: the-matrix

Thanks to this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/who-is-the-highest-authority-of-the-machine-world-in-the-matrixverse?rq=1) I now understand that The Architect and the Deus Ex Machina are two different entities. Before, I always thought they were one and the same because of the [last scene in Matrix Revolutions](https://youtu.be/5ozBRWmZuF4?t=56s).

We know that the Deus Ex Machina makes an agreement with Neo and and in the last scene, The Architect says that he will allow those still inside the Matrix tro be set free and because he is not Human he *will* keep his promise(!). It always felt like *he* was the one making the deal with Neo because of that.

**If The Architect is not the Deus ex Machina then why is the Oracle trying to get him to agree to free the people inside the Matrix? And if he isn't the top authority, how come he can make independent decisions on such a big issue?**

Comment: There doesn't have to be a hierarchy; the machines could simply be attempting to reestablish homeostasis.  The old loop--- use Zion as a relief valve, wait for the One to emerge and rouse the rabble, destroy Zion, reseed Zion, repeat--- was broken and proven unreliable by the emergence of the Smith virus.  They needed a new plan.  Who better than the designer of the system to chart a new course?

Comment: Also, assuming the programs, or top level programs at least, are networked and sharing all data simultaneously the Architect could have communed with any other leader-class programs and reached a consensus nearly immediately. That he/it was the one communicating that decision to the Oracle was merely happenstance.

Comment: @Xantec That's an interesting concept.  The programs have individuality but can form ad-hoc collectives at will.

Comment: @zabeus I hadn't intended to imply a collective, but that is a possibility. I had meant perhaps they do their equivalent of a conference call.